# convert string to Chips in a textField

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-chips

I want to convert text which is in a EditText to [chips](https://material.google.com/components/chips.html#chips-usage)

There are a lot of libraries for and related question to it like [this](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips) , [this](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691984/how-to-set-chips-from-string-in-edittext-in-android). All of them are hard to understand (at least for me ), because all of those library have features I am not interested in.

I want to convert a text to chips  which is entered into an EditText (programmatically). Is there a straight forward way to do it?

P.s. by saying `Straight Forward` i meant  i dont want this auto completion , suggestions and the text that am entering is entered programmatically not manually

Comment: "do we have any straight Forward way to do it ?" -- libraries are going to be as simple as you are going to get. This capability is not built into Android itself and is not especially easy to implement.

Comment: @CommonsWare by saying `Straight Forward` i meant  i dont want this auto completion , suggestions and the text that am entering is entered programmatically not manually

Comment: Then why are you using an `EditText`? The point behind an `EditText` is for the user to enter text. If you want the user to enter text, but also have some chips, put the chips outside the `EditText`.

Comment: all right i can do that but my question is how to get the chips @CommonsWare , basically am selecting some string from a list and i want to show that list in  a box in the for of chips

Comment: Off the cuff, a chip would just be a `TextView` with a suitable background (e.g., nine-patch PNG, `ShapeDrawable, `VectorDrawable`).

Comment: or i can use this https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView library , exactly what i was searching for , thanks for your effort  :)